# Overlay text search box onto image and maintain aspect ratio of background image

Tags: html, css

I want my webpage's search bar to be over a custom image so that the user is typing on top of the image, but I would like it to be able to still remain legible and sized correctly for any screen size, as well as ensuring the text stays aligned with the image properly. This will also allow me to make sure the search button is always directly beside the entry, instead of leaving blank space as it currently does.

Here is the css and html for the search bar

```
.group-guesses {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 60px;
    width: 80%;
}
.autocomplete{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width:85%;
    background-image: url("images/emptyChatBubbleExtended.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

form.search-form input[type=text] {
    padding-left: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: transparent;
    width:85%;
    min-height: 100px;
    float:left;
}
form.search-form button{
    padding: 10px;
    color: #191919;
    border: 1px solid #8f6d07;
    font-family: customScript;
    width:15%;
    float:right;
}
```

```
<div class="group-guesses" id="groupGuessesMade">
    <div class="group-guess-input" id="my-group-guess-input">
        <form class="search-form" autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="autocomplete">
                <input id="guessEntry" type="text" name="myGuess" placeholder="Guess">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" onclick="guess()" id="guessButton" class="guess-button">Guess</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```